# Unable to register schame using Avro with Nested class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium, apicurio-registry

Whenever there is nested object in Avro class schema is not getting saved
always get exception like

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:223)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:149)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:330)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:356)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:258)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
connect_1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
connect_1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
connect_1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
connect_1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
connect_1    |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
connect_1    | Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.put(Schema.java:1550)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$NamedSchema.writeNameRef(Schema.java:813)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:975)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema.toJson(Schema.java:1242)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.fieldsToJson(Schema.java:1003)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema.toJson(Schema.java:987)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(Schema.java:426)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(Schema.java:398)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(Schema.java:389)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroKafkaSerializer.getSchemaFromData(AvroKafkaSerializer.java:108)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.AbstractKafkaSerializer.lambda$serialize$0(AbstractKafkaSerializer.java:90)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.LazyLoadedParsedSchema.getRawSchema(LazyLoadedParsedSchema.java:55)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.DefaultSchemaResolver.resolveSchema(DefaultSchemaResolver.java:81)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.AbstractKafkaSerializer.serialize(AbstractKafkaSerializer.java:92)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.serde.AbstractKafkaSerializer.serialize(AbstractKafkaSerializer.java:79)
connect_1    |  at io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.SerdeBasedConverter.fromConnectData(SerdeBasedConverter.java:111)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:64)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$3(WorkerSourceTask.java:330)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:173)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207)
connect_1    |  ... 11 more
```

Tools useed

1. Debezium
2. Apicurio Schema registry
3. Avro format

Comment: could you add your schema you have tried to save?

Comment: Do you have any chance to update the `AvroKafkaSerializer` you're using? I think a colleague of mine hit a similar issue a few months back, and I _think_ in our case using a version after this PR solved it:
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/2186
I see you're using a version shadowed by apicurio, which I'm not familiar about, although maybe just upgrading your libs somehow migh help?

Comment: Hi @Svend I am using latest version of confluentinc/cp-schema-registry

Comment: Hi @nipuna This is only happening because of nested object, if i dont have any nested object it workes well

Comment: The stack trace shows that the serializer used it `io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroKafkaSerializer`, is there any reason to use this one instead of `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer` ?

Comment: Hi @Svend I tried with confluent serializer also

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
connect_1             |         at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:154)
connect_1             |         at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:153)

connect_1             | Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault

Comment: I recall someone being able to fix that error with this transform https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html

Comment: Feel free to post your complete solution below as an answer